# WPF MVVM UI not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, observablecollection

I'm having a problem with updating the UI in WPF using MVVM.

I've got a ObservableCollection which is displayed in a ItemsControl.
When you click on it, i want to add something to this ObservableCollection and show it.

But here is where it goes wrong, it's not showing in the UI.
After debugging i found out that the item is actually added to the ObservableCollection.

I have no clue what the problem is, your help is much appreciated.

XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:BoardViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoardViewModel x:Key="obj"  />
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="Checkerboard" Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,2,2" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Tan">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,2,2" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Brown">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1" />
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="1,1,1,1" />
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>

    <Style x:Key="ChessPieceStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.Pawn}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.White}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_white_pawn_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.Rook}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.White}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_white_rook_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.Knight}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.White}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_white_knight_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.Bishop}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.White}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_white_bishop_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.Queen}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.White}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_white_queen_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.King}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.White}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_white_king_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.Pawn}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.Black}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_black_pawn_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.Rook}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.Black}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_black_rook_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.Knight}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.Black}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_black_knight_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.Bishop}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.Black}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_black_bishop_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.Queen}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.Black}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_black_queen_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Static local:PieceType.King}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Player}" Value="{x:Static local:Player.Black}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/chess/chess_set_1/chess_piece_black_king_T.png" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Viewbox>
    <ItemsControl Name="ChessBoard" ItemsSource="{Binding Pieces}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="8" Height="8"  Background="{StaticResource Checkerboard}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="1" Height="1" >
                    <local:CustomImage  Width="0.8" Height="0.8" Style="{StaticResource ChessPieceStyle}" >
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDoubleClickEvent">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding btnClick, Source={StaticResource obj }}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </local:CustomImage>                        
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Pos.X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Pos.Y}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

Board

```
 class Board
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChessPiece> pieces { get; set; }

    public Board()
    {
        pieces = new ObservableCollection<ChessPiece>();
        // White
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece{Pos=new Point(0, 6), Type=PieceType.Pawn, Player=Player.White});
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece{Pos=new Point(1, 6), Type=PieceType.Pawn, Player=Player.White});
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece{Pos=new Point(2, 6), Type=PieceType.Pawn, Player=Player.White});
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(3, 6), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(4, 6), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(5, 6), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(6, 6), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(7, 6), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(0, 7), Type = PieceType.Rook, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(1, 7), Type = PieceType.Knight, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(2, 7), Type = PieceType.Bishop, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(3, 7), Type = PieceType.Queen, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(4, 7), Type = PieceType.King, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(5, 7), Type = PieceType.Bishop, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(6, 7), Type = PieceType.Knight, Player = Player.White });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(7, 7), Type = PieceType.Rook, Player = Player.White }); 

        // Black
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(0, 1), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(1, 1), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(2, 1), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(3, 1), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(4, 1), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(5, 1), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(6, 1), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(7, 1), Type = PieceType.Pawn, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(0, 0), Type = PieceType.Rook, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(1, 0), Type = PieceType.Knight, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(2, 0), Type = PieceType.Bishop, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(3, 0), Type = PieceType.Queen, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(4, 0), Type = PieceType.King, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(5, 0), Type = PieceType.Bishop, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(6, 0), Type = PieceType.Knight, Player = Player.Black });
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(7, 0), Type = PieceType.Rook, Player = Player.Black }); 
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        pieces.Add(new ChessPiece { Pos = new Point(3, 4), Type = PieceType.Rook, Player = Player.Black});
    }
}
```

BoardViewModel:

```
 class BoardViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ChessPiece> _pieces;
    private Board _board;

    private ButtonClick objCommand;
    public ObservableCollection<ChessPiece> Pieces
    {
        get { return _pieces; }           
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public BoardViewModel()
    {
        _board = new Board();

        _pieces = _board.pieces;
        objCommand = new ButtonClick(this);
    }

    public void DoMove()
    {
        _board.Move();

        if (PropertyChanged != null) // Point 2
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Pieces"));
        // Point 3
        }
    }

    public ICommand btnClick // Point 3
    {
        get
        {
            return objCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

ButtonClick

```
class ButtonClick : ICommand
{
    private BoardViewModel _model;

    public ButtonClick(BoardViewModel m)
    {
        _model = m;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        // When to execute
        // Validation logic goes here
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // What to Execute
        // Execution logic goes here
        _model.DoMove();
    }
}
```

CustomImage

```
    public class CustomImage : Image
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The mouse left button double click event
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly RoutedEvent MouseLeftButtonDoubleClick =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
            "MouseLeftButtonDoubleClick",
            RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
            typeof(CustomImage));

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when [mouse left button double click event handler].
    /// </summary>
    public event RoutedEventHandler MouseLeftButtonDoubleClickEvent
    {
        add
        {
            AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDoubleClick, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            RemoveHandler(MouseLeftButtonDoubleClick, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when an unhandled <see cref="E:System.Windows.UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown" /> 
    /// routed event is raised on this element. Implement this method to add class handling for 
    /// this event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="T:System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs" /> that 
    /// contains the event data. The event data reports that the left mouse button was pressed.
    /// </param>
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Double-click
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            RaiseEvent(new MouseLeftButtonDoubleClickEventArgs(
                MouseLeftButtonDoubleClick, this));
        }
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// MouseLeftButtonDoubleClick EventArgs.
    /// </summary>
    public class MouseLeftButtonDoubleClickEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MouseLeftButtonDoubleClickEventArgs"/> 
        /// class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="routedEvent">The routed event identifier for this instance of the 
        /// <see cref="T:System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs" /> class.</param>
        /// <param name="source">An alternate source that will be reported when the event is 
        /// handled. This pre-populates the
        /// <see cref="P:System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.Source" /> property.</param>
        public MouseLeftButtonDoubleClickEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent, object source)
            : base(routedEvent, source)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

ChessPieceType:

```
 public class ChessPiece : ViewModelBase
{
    private Point _Pos;
    public Point Pos
    {
        get { return this._Pos; }
        set { this._Pos = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Pos); }
    }

    private PieceType _Type;
    public PieceType Type
    {
        get { return this._Type; }
        set { this._Type = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Type); }
    }

    private Player _Player;
    public Player Player
    {
        get { return this._Player; }
        set { this._Player = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Player); }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two places where you are storing your pieces. In `Board`, and in the `BoardViewModel` (Which is a reference to the collection in `Board`). When you say *"After debugging i found out that the item is actually added to the ObservableCollection"*, to which collection are you referring to?

Comment: It's updated in both collections

Comment: I can't see anything that is wrong with your code. Perhaps the board piece is displayed on the view, but is in front, or behind another piece on the same square? Either that or the image for the piece was not loaded, and the piece is invisible.

Comment: You have two instances of your viewmodel. One in datacontext, another in resources. Maybe you are adding items to the wrong instance

Comment: another error: you are binding to `Pieces` but in your viewmodel you have defined 'pieces'. have you checked messages in output window while debugging?